# Inverse Probability Selection (Inverse Fitness Selection of Evolutionary Algorithms)

Tags: algorithm, probability, genetic-algorithm

I need to probabilistically select a sample from a set of data.

Say I had a set of values `array[12, 15, 29, 17, 12, 29]`.  The standard approach would be calculate the total (12 + 15 + 29 + 17 + 12 + 29) and then create a spinner that favors the higher value.  Kinda like a pie chart where we select at random from the sample set but favor the Individual with the highest value.

An example with the numbers above the chance you will randomly select `array[0]` is 11% while the chance that `array[5]` is 25%.  That's fine

What I want to do though is favor the lower numbers and with all my brainstorming power I cannot figure out a way to give the lower number a statistically equal probability of selection as if we were to select the larger number.

One way I have approached the problem is to add `array[]` then subtract each value from the total giving you a `array2[102, 99, 85, 102, 85]` then recalculating the percents from `array2[].` Giving `array[0]` a 21%.  The problem with this solution is that elements with close statistical probability of selection in `array[1]` have distant selection percentages.

We also attempted just swapping the lowest and highest then next lowest with next highest percent values but that gives you the same problem as our first attempt.

I feel like there has to be an easy way to to this.

Note:  If you are familiar with Evolutionary/Genetic Computation we are trying to do parent    selection based on fitness proportion.  However, our fitness value is reversed (the lower the better).  So how do we do fitness proportion selection for parents if the lower the fitness the better?

Comment: I can't figure out what you want. Your 4th paragraph says "favor the lower numbers...give the lower number a statistically equal probability" which is a contradiction. What do you want? Each number has the same probability, 1/5 in this case, or something else?

Comment: What I mean is you favor the lower numbers with a statistically equal probability as if we used the selection method of high numbers.

Comment: can you describe the problem with your first approach more clearly? what is the meaning of "elements with close statistical probability of selection" and "distant selection percentages"?

Comment: Leave genome selection as it is - instead MAXIMIZE function -> fitness = 1/your_old_fitness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you work with inverses? The base array for the probabilities in your example would be `array[1.0/12, 1.0/15, 1.0/29, 1.0/17, 1.0/12, 1.0/29]`, the rest would stay the same.